# How to count the syllables in a word

Tags: code-challenge, word

**Input:** You will be passed a string containing a single english word.  All letters will be lowercase, and there will be no non-alphabetic characters in the string.

**Output:** You will return an integer from 1 to 7 representing how many syllables you think are in the word.

**Scoring:** Your program will be run against all of the words found on [this repository](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/wordsbysyllables).  If you get `N` words correct, and your program is `M` bytes large, then your score is `N-(M*10)`.  Largest score wins.

To generate my syllable count, I used [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/PG/2006/04/1-10000) as my word list and [this](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3204) to count the syllables.

Comment: The 3-syllable-words contains "inn" and "ruby". The 2-syllable-words contains these: "irs", "ore", "roy", "yer". Other than that the lists seem accurate enough.

Comment: @justhalf thank you for those catches.  Creating the lists was definitely the hardest part of the challenge.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/build-a-readability-index

Comment: This challenge is making me realise how silly English can be. Take `resume` for example...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Ruby, 8618 correct (91.1%), 53 bytes, 8618 - 10 * 53 = 8088 score

```rb
->s{s.scan(/[aiouy]+e*|e(?!d$|ly).|[td]ed|le$/).size}
```

This is an anonymous Ruby function which uses regexes to count syllables.

The function adds a syllable for every instance of:

- A run of non-`e` vowels, followed by zero of more `e`s
- An `e` which is *not* part of a trailing `ed` or `ely`, with the exception of trailing `ted` or `ded`s
- A trailing `le`

### Analysis

The basic idea is to count runs of vowels, but this by itself isn't very accurate (`[aeiouy]+` gets 74% correct). The main reason for this is because of the [silent `e`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e), which modifies the previous vowel sound while not being pronounced itself. For example, the word `slate` has two vowels but only one syllable.

To deal with this, we take `e` out of the first part of the regex and treat it separately. Detecting silent `e`s is hard, but I found two cases where they occur often:

- As part of a trailing `ed` (unless it's a `ted` or `ded` like `settled` or `saddled`),
- As part of a trailing `evy` (e.g. `lovely`)

These cases are specifically excluded in what would otherwise be `e.`.

The reason for the `.` in `e(?!d$|ly).` is to consume the next char if there is a double vowel (e.g. `ea` or `ee`), and so that `e` at the end of the word are not counted. However a trailing `le` *is* usually pronounced, so that is added back in.

Finally, vowel runs are counted as one syllable. While this may not always be the case (e.g. `curious`), it's often difficult to work out whether there are multiple syllables. Take the `ia` of `celestial` and `spatial`, as an example.

### Test program

I don't really know Ruby so I'm not sure how well it can be golfed. I did manage to scrape together a test program by consulting a lot of SO though:

```rb
cases = 0
correct = 0

s = "->s{s.scan(/[aiouy]+e*|e(?!d$|ly).|[td]ed|le$/).size}"

f = eval s

for i in 1 ... 8
    filepath = i.to_s + "-syllable-words.txt"
    file = File.open(filepath)

    while (line = file.gets)
        word = line.strip
        cases += 1
        if f.call(word) == i
            correct += 1
        end
    end
end

p "Correct: #{correct}/#{cases}, Length: #{s.length}, Score: #{correct - s.length*10}"
```

Comment: Aww, you made the standard so high. In Python the code length is exactly 20 chars longer, so my implementation of your "Vowel followed by a letter that's not `e`" gives 6638 (7158 correct)

Comment: @justhalf It's basically the only reason why I'm using Ruby :P I normally use Python for everything else.

Answer (score 5):

## Python3, 7935 - 10 * 71 = 7225

My quick-and-dirty answer: count runs of consecutive vowels, but remove any final e's first.

```
lambda w:len(''.join(" x"[c in"aeiouy"]for c in w.rstrip('e')).split())
```

After stripping off the e's, this replaces vowels with `x` and all other characters with a space. The result is joined back into a string and then split on whitespace. Conveniently, whitespace at the beginning and end is ignored (e.g. `" x xx ".split()` gives `["x","xx"]`). The length of the resulting list is therefore the number of vowel groups.

The original, 83-byte answer below was more accurate because it only removed a single e at the end. The newer one thus has problems for words like `bee`; but the shortened code outweighs that effect.

```
lambda w:len(''.join(" x"[c in"aeiouy"]for c in(w[:-1]if'e'==w[-1]else w)).split())
```

Test program:

```
syll = lambda w:len(''.join(c if c in"aeiouy"else' 'for c in w.rstrip('e')).split())

overallCorrect = overallTotal = 0
for i in range(1, 7):
    with open("%s-syllable-words.txt" % i) as f:
        words = f.read().split()
    correct = sum(syll(word) == i for word in words)
    total = len(words)
    print("%s: %s correct out of %s (%.2f%%)" % (i, correct, total, 100*correct/total))
    overallCorrect += correct
    overallTotal += total

print()
print("%s correct out of %s (%.2f%%)" % (overallCorrect, overallTotal, 100*overallCorrect/overallTotal))
```

Evidently this was too dirty and not quick enough to beat Sp3000's Ruby answer. ;^)

Comment: `->s{s.scan(/([aiouy]|e(?!$))+/).size}` scores 7583. 84%'s pretty impressive for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 8145 - 3 * 30 = 7845

Using the lists from before the recent commits.

```
#!perl -lp
$_=s/(?!e[ds]?$)[aeiouy]+//g
```

Comment: The files have been updated recently. I took a look and didn't see the words you named in the 1 syllable file.

Comment: @Sp3000, weired. They where updated 7 hours ago according to what I see, and there are still those words under that link: https://github.com/nathanmerrill/wordsbysyllables/blob/master/1-syllable-words.txt

Comment: Looks like @NathanMerrill messed up the update 7 hours ago: [history](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/wordsbysyllables/commit/435e99f073f2c2e644f80747d334f6407f175a59).

Comment: @Sp3000, thanks. I update the score to the older version. Those lists still have quite a few errors, but not as severe.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 5370-10*19 = 5180

This program simply assumes that longer words means more syllables.

```
lambda x:len(x)/6+1
```

The tester program I use is:

```
correct = 0
y = lambda x:len(x)/6+1
for i in xrange(1,8):
    f = file(str(i)+"-syllable-words.txt")
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
    correct += len([1 for line in lines if y(line)==i])
print correct
```

Comment: Should we create a program or a function? Yours is not a program, it outputs nothing when run.

Comment: @justhalf I need something that accepts input and produces output (even if that output isn't STDIO)

Comment: Btw I didn't get 5150 for using 7, but 4391. In my test it's better to use `len(x)/6` instead (5377-190 = 5187).

Comment: @justhalf With the updates, I'm getting 5343, but definitely getting a worse score with len(x)/6.  I'll post my test program.

Comment: `readlines()` includes the newline in the result. So yours is actually `(len(x)+1)/7+1`. You should use `read().split('\n')` instead. Although I got 5352 for that formula, though.