# Greek Syllabication (Simplified)

Tags: code-golf, natural-language, word-puzzle

### INTRO

Let's say you write a passage and you are close to the end of the line wanting to write down a large word. In most languages, you just leave some blank and move to the next line, like a sir.

> Example - English:

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah   blah this man is      unaccountable

But if you are (un)lucky enough to be Greek, when you are close to terminate a line, you cannot just move to the next one. Everything must look nice and in balance, so you SEPARATE the word

> Example - Greek:

μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα μπλα αυτός ο άνδρας είναι ανεξή-
γητος

Of course this separation is not done randomly, but instead there is a complicated set of rules, as to how & when to separate, which is actually an entire learning chapter back in primary school that every kid hates.

### OBJECTIVE

You are given a greek word (just a string of greek letters). You need to do a greek syllabication, i.e. separate the greek word in syllabes, according to the set of rules given below, so that the user will have the option to separate the word in the end of the line correctly.

Examples:
1) αγαπη (love) = α-γα-πη
2) ακροπολη (acropolis) = α-κρο-πο-λη
3) βασικα (basically) = βα-σι-κα

### ALPHABET & SIMPLIFIED RULES

**consonants:** β,γ,δ,ζ,θ,κ,λ,μ,ν,ξ,π,ρ,σ,τ,φ,χ,ψ

**vowels:** α,ε,η,ι,ο,υ,ω

**rule 0)** Every vowel defines a different syllable, unless rule 4

**rule 1)** When there is consonant between two vowels, it goes with the second vowel
(ex. γ --> α-**γ**α-πη)

**rule 2)** When there are two consonants between two vowels, they go with the second vowel, if there is a greek word starting from these two consonants (we assume that that's always the case in our exercise)
(ex. βλ --> βι-**βλ**ι-ο)

**rule 3)** When we have 3 consonants between two vowels-->same as rule 2

**rule 4)** Following configurations are considered as "one letter" and are never separated: ει, οι, υι, αι, ου, μπ, ντ, γκ, τσ, τζ
(ex. α-**γκυ**-ρα)

**rule 5)** Always separate same consonants
(ex. α**λ-λ**η)

### YOUR TASK

Your code should take as input string (or some other format you wish) a greek word and return the same word, with dashes in between, determining the points where the word can be separated, i.e. do a greek syllabication.

```
TestCases:

[πολη (city)] --> [πο-λη]  
[τρεχω (run)] --> [τρε-χω]  
[αναβαση (climbing)] --> [α-να-βα-ση]  
[οαση (oasis)] --> [ο-α-ση]  
[ουρα (tail)] --> [ου-ρα]  
[μπαινω (enter)] --> [μπαι-νω]  
[εχθροι (enemies)] --> [ε-χθροι]  
[ελλαδα (greece)] --> [ελ-λα-δα]  
[τυροπιτα (cheese pie)] --> [τυ-ρο-πι-τα]  
[αρρωστη (sick)] --> [αρ-ρω-στη]
```

Shortest code wins, but every effort is appreciated :)

Comment: [(Loosely) Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47322/how-to-count-the-syllables-in-a-word)

Comment: Did the greeks change the monotonic system to a-tonic due to economic crisis?

Comment: Mathematica has a syllabication/hyphenation built-in that only works for English words. 25 bytes: `#~WordData~"Hyphenation"&`

Comment: `with dashes in between` -- Is returning an array of strings okay?

Comment: It seems like it's possible to scrap part of rule 4, is there a missing test case?

Comment: @bartavelle your code should not only work for the given testcases, but for all cases that can be created according to the rules. It would be a lot of work to generate a testcase for every configuration of the 4th rule.

Comment: @ovs I understand, but as they are consonants only, I don't see how removing them changes the algorithm

Comment: Perhaps with somethingl like "μππ" ?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy:i didn't include tones, for simplicity, otherwise it gets really complicated    

@ JungHwan Min: Yes, format output is up to you    

@ bartavelle: Rule 4 is put mainly for the vowels. In practice it is used for consonants as well (if in rule 2,3 there is no greek work), but in our simplified version, it wont be needed.

Comment: @koita_pisw_sou oh wow, this really looks complicated!

Comment: @bartavelle: yeah and there are also some rules on top of that including special cases and tones. but for simplicity as i said, i have removed all those restrictions and assumed there is always a greek word in case of conflict

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>222</strike> 201 bytes

```hs
s""=[]
s x|c?"ειοιυιαιου"=(a++c):s d|h:e:f:g<-b,e==f=(a++[h,e]):s(f:g)|e:f<-b=(a++[e]):s f|2>1=[a]where(a,b)=break(`elem`"αεηιουω")x;(c,d)=splitAt 2 b 
i?(x:y:z)=i==[x,y]||i?z
i?""=1>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLNattAEL7rKYY97WL1EB/VbkwugdCUHHoUopHldSQsq8ZSiRJ0qIlDyeM41CTGNX6D3UdyZkdSq4TSSojd@X7mZ1dxmE9Umh4OOWPSD5wcyioaML3WG73XG3OP68ruzT2TPOz1IuHlMKpiT3lj7@rDu6GrpBwT5ceuCpDmSIgKeWRrgmAYV/3jI@mHwXWs5oqH7lDI4VyFE36pUjW9ZFhprZ/qauaBifI9j9yRkPksTYqTAvowBCcZ8NK78W6FTKT0S/cmqKpkcIs4TnB03D8UKi9y8Dzw@edinmRXLvj1JhCBU7MSHMDHB87Mdxx0q58YyijADSMgECRyrWhpFnptfmBXJKPQCgnqCHGEHX6PemXumpx6RRl3zfpYr0R3jfuuBZsg319keDQLSuFTQLks0BX9wjnsre2aflvAZt29aRin0s@YYW9pq13bsn@wV1o8ly0m@tk2gIDNuaVeCX59aLbXPdbemGVjsaAtsKAZLWWX5ZsBVmaB74O5Q6Y9RbMgnx2JNURjCcBxpmGS2Us/uwAu6kjCNJx9@gJRrKIJ0MU7QP@eddUoT7LZt8IFVc5UVKiRQFcyhhwIByl/M1TpH08RqwzQg7/aeYYzXHz0gEGvV2cS/7OrNFdd@@nJ2Xk3gd2wOs7jr9fA277ctlkhnMML)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 183 bytes

```py
def f(s,r=''):
 for p,c in zip(' '+s,s):
  if p in'αεηιουω'and(p+c)not in 'ει,οι,υι,αι,ου,μπ,ντ,γκ,τσ,τζ'or p==c:yield r+p;r=''
  elif p>' ':r+=p
 yield r+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBLTsNADN3nFFY2M1EGNuyC0osgFlE@YlA1GaVZpKxaNRHqcQIqVYGqN7CPFGzSLsaaZz/7Pduv25faPUxTUVZQ6ZVpUqWiJICqbsCbHKyDN@u1AhWvzEoqYCvwnFc44gGPeMILDbRXmSu0j/PI1a10KS6eDF440CC/8R/SYPCXNgbP1Bv8xG9DPe044JcSyTTNk7UtlwU0sX8UN6xYLkVzwSaSJk59ADdGPmWQwhNTAELasNoPHkMDM@5piwd6p31oZgZ7OPP7wJF2My/kliu4UmSZLY63IWJWrLNfGfMcBHKZTjbM5Bi@sa7VnQGVLhTHO3X/WlunK91FUTT9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + sed, <s>188</s> 187 bytes

```bash
sed -re $(echo 's/([^@\1/\1-\1/g;s/[εουα]ι|ου|μπ|ντ|γκ|τσ|τζ|./-&/g;s/!(!)?(!)?([@/\1\3\5\6/g;s/-([^@(-|$)/\1/g;s/-+/-/g;s/.//'|sed 's/!/([^-@-/g;s/@/αεηιουω])/g')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU9LTsMwEN3nFIlUkUSVa1UINizIPeIi8YnaHVKz9aJRiqocx0AJplS5wZsjhecAsmY04/fx88N9vRnHunqK1baKZ1n1uHmO01pn5V1hltosFfv6ptYljhjkBW4Fb8Nk8S07i7PsLd7wZWUvLRs@7EKri0mTZEl@O1VZ0MpcmitzPSEq@GfKznL956/mWk3DQuvUhkBMkYQcqvgFCg3HED18eF66Va7XaT6OssOAE/qICRoc5SBdROaZ9QonLRES/gcqG7gohCfBMz/ZFOGT9wM8F5qdiL2TRsvAH0j2/Bt1ThqeTlqu/Q8)

Uses a sed program compressed with... sed. The actual sed program looks like this:

```bash
# replace consecutive consonants: αρρωστη -> αρ-ρωστη
s/([^αεηιουω])\1/\1-\1/g
# separate "letters": αρ-ρωστη -> -α-ρ---ρ-ω-σ-τ-η
s/[εουα]ι|ου|μπ|ντ|γκ|τσ|τζ|./-&/g
# attach preceding consonants to vowels: -α-ρ---ρ-ω-σ-τ-η -> -α-ρ---ρω-στη
s/([^-αεηιουω])-(([^-αεηιουω])-)?(([^-αεηιουω])-)?([αεηιουω])/\1\3\5\6/g
# attach lone consonants to previous vowel: -α-ρ---ρω-στη -> -αρ--ρω-στη
s/-([^αεηιουω])(-|$)/\1/g
# remove extra dashes: -αρ--ρω-στη -> -αρ-ρω-στη
s/-+/-/g
# remove initial dash: -αρ-ρω-στη -> αρ-ρω-στη
s/.//
```