# Counting syllables

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

### Challenge

Write code that, given an English word, outputs the number of [syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable) it has. Scoring will be determined by a combination of code length and accuracy.

### Rules

- **The accuracy of the solution should be measured against [this CSV file](https://gist.github.com/Udzu/60d6781ae441344506c38ac827079b03)** (which countains syllable counts for all the 52,439 entries in the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMU_Pronouncing_Dictionary) that are also words listed in the [SOWPODS Scrabble Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collins_Scrabble_Words)).
- Entries should accept any word listed in the file and return a numeric value for it; behaviour on other inputs is left undefined. Note that the words listed are all lower-case and between 2 and 15 letters long.
- The returned syllable count is correct if it corresponds to *any* of the listed counts for that word. Note that some words have multiple correct syllable counts, which are separated with a '|' in the CSV: eg

```
resume,2|3
resumed,2
resumes,2|3
resuming,3
```

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.

### Scoring

This is a modified [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), with the total score being **the sum of the code length in bytes and the square of percentage error** (which is first rounded to the nearest percent). For example:

- `lambda s:2` has a score of 10 (bytes) + 61*61 (squared % error) = 3731
- `lambda s:sum(s.count(v)for v in "aeiouy")` has a score of 41 + 45*45 = 2066.

Comment: [Related / possible dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47322/52210) (difference is the given word-list to test against and scoring formula). I don't have the time to build a test-suite (might do so tomorrow), but I wonder what percentage the regex of that accepted answer would match in the list of this challenge.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That is quite similar, isn't it? :-( I've tested the top Ruby answer and it scores 86.52%, which gives an overall score of 53 + 13^2 = 222. I can personally do a bit better, but perhaps it's too similar to be of interest.

Comment: Should I just close it as duplicate?

Comment: [175](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoQgEADQswR@6EbN137GHkQsBhxCclPUAmHO3vRephK/ImpbtDYLWAzp6m6kD5P@DV5x7GZm27wjz5EU7GaEoJEvrn9Odj2d4R5gAtuO21EFEcTibyzHk3IL6awy5Rc) (75 bytes, 10.44% incorrect words).